# Removing letters and making them lowercase in R

Tags: r

```
df$Ad.clean <- tolower(stri_trans_general(df$Ad.clean, "latin-ascii")).
```

I am getting this error. See below:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Ad.clean, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 169666.
```

Comment: Hi Zymantas, welcome to SO. not very clear why it doesn't work. can you do dput(head(df,5)) and paste the output as part of your post

Comment: this way, others can reproduce your error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What you mean with dput(head(df,5))?

Comment: V7 = c("", "", "", "", ""), V8 = c("", "", "", "", ""), V9 = c("", 
    "", "", "", ""), V10 = c("", "", "", "", ""), V11 = c("", 
    "", "", "", ""), V12 = c("", "", "", "", ""), V13 = c("", ")

Comment: Run this code `dput(head(df, 5))` on your R console and copy/paste the output to your question!

Comment: Yeah but very unclear output seems. I thought case like does the excel to csv conversation impact data structure?